# tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ERROR

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview, sigabrt, uitableview

Hi I was following tutorial of this website . http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/

Once finished I run it and I get a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I get the error on this line above.

Here is my full code, well not mine, but they guy who owns the web site's.

Main File

```
//
//  APPMaster.m
//  fcffv
//
//  Created by Ajay Venkat on 7/09/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AJTech. All rights reserved.
//

#import "APPMaster.h"
#import "APPDetail.h"
@interface APPMaster () {

    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;

}
@end
@implementation APPMaster
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}
@end
```

Header File

```
//
//  APPMaster.h
//  fcffv
//
//  Created by Ajay Venkat on 7/09/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AJTech. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface APPMaster : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

Hope you can help.
Thanks.

If you really have enough time here is the full Project

https://www.mediafire.com/?ebajcg33gkl2jf3

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: You need to register nib if you are using one. Please post your code and stack trace

Comment: Guys I am gonna paste the media fire link, would be awesome if you could skim through it https://www.mediafire.com/?ebajcg33gkl2jf3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy and pasted your code into an Xcode file and it worked out fine... There's a few you things you should probably double check though...

1. Did you set the cell identifier of the prototype cell in the storyboard to "Cell"?
2. Xcode is giving me an error on the setUrl (you should probably change it to setURL) method on the destination viewController, so I commented it out and it worked fine.

hope this helps...

Comment: Point 1. is almost definitely the answer. It isn't mentioned in the tutorial but perhaps the default reuse identifier has changed.

Comment: the reason you are getting the setURL is because there is another header and main file which I have not given, you import it with '#'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a static NSString.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

This was before the implementation in the ".m" file

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That is what I changed and, YAY. Like user3192218 said I changed the identifier to match the storyboard and it worked.